# Apache Superset oauth2 with custom Spring-Security OAuth2 server

Tags: spring, apache, flask, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using [Apache Superset](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/) and trying to configure its OAuth2 capability to connect to my (custom) [Spring-Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) OAuth2 server.  Unfortunately, it ain't working right now.  The stack track begins with this.

> 15:09:16.584 [qtp1885996206-21] ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/oauth/authorize] due to exception [Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/confirm_access' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/confirm_access' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1262) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE] at

Here is the relevant portion of my `config.py` from Superset.

```
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
            "name" : "MY-OAUTH",
            "icon" : APP_ICON,
            "token_key" : "password",
            "remote_app" : {
                    "consumer_key" : "my_dashboard",
                    "consumer_secret" : "my_secret",
                    "base_url" : "http://localhost:8088/myoauth",
                    "request_token_params" : {
                            "scope": "my_dashboard read write",
                            "grant_type" : "password"
                    },
                    "request_token_url" : None,
                    "access_token_url" : "http://localhost:8088/myoauth/oauth/token",
                    "access_token_params" : {
                            "scope": "my_dashboard read write",
                            "grant_type" : "password",
                            "response_type" : "authorization_code"
                    },
                    "access_token_method" : "POST",
                    "authorize_url" : "http://localhost:8088/myoauth/oauth/authorize"
            }
    }
]
```

A nice gentleman suggested that I have somehow disabled the servlet handler for `/oauth/confirm_access`, but I am not sure how to check on that or fix such a problem.

Do you know what is going on here, what I can do to fix this or where I can start looking?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Also, I set the environment variable to allow OAuth2 without SSL.

Comment: any progress ?? have you solved the problem?